# Pleiades atmospheric correction

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, erdas-imagine, atmospheric-correction, flaash

I have phr1a and phr1b images (Pleiades) and I need to make atmospheric correction. First, I tried to do this by using Envi FLAASH. by the way, I tried also ERDAS atcor but there was also same conversion problem. I did radiometric correction but I couldn't do atmospheric correction because every time the software has the error of  ACC error:convert7. Does anybody have any idea how to overcome this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLAASH in envi is very sensitive.

1) your result must be saved in other drives (not drive C).
2) you should make a folder for saving FLAASH result specifically.
3) you should enter any name as root name, because the root name box in empty.
4) you should enter a single address for output reflectance file and output directories.

good luck,

Comment: Why can't it be saved to a location on C?, seems a major drawback if your PC only has a C: drive.  Perhaps it can only be save to drives that have public write?